# Azure Self hosted Gateway with client certificates

Tags: azure, api, azure-api-management, client-certificates

how to protect the APIs on a self hosted gateway from unauthorized use with client certificates?

The documentation on this topic is too unclear for me:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-ca-certificates#create-custom-ca-for-self-hosted-gateway

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is to give the right common name/dns name during the creation of the certificate. After that a gateway hostname must be created inside the gatewaypanel of the self hosted gateway and the uploaded certificate addded and check the checkbox negotiate clientcertificates.